# Script error : "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I know this question has been asked several times, I tried to find a solution but I found nothing. I am trying to create a graph chart.js.

the part that contains the error is that of '**option:**', because when I delete it all works well, but despite that I check well, I do not find the error

here is my error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

here is my script:

```
<script>

var timeFormat = 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss';
function newDateLabel(dateObject) {
    val_date = moment(dateObject).format(timeFormat);
    return new Date(val_date)
}

var config = {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'line',

    data: {
        labels: [
            %for time in list_date:
                newDateLabel('{{time}}'),
            %end
        ],

        datasets: [{
            label: 'Demo',

            fill: false,

            data: [
                %for val in list_valeurs:
                    {{val}},
                %end
            ],

            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },

    options: {
        title: {
            text: 'Chart.js Time Scale'
        },

        scales: {

            xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                    format: timeFormat,
                    tooltipFormat: 'll HH:mm'
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Date'
                }
            }],

            yAxes: [{
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'value'
                }
            }]

        },
    }

};

window.onload = function() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx,config);

};
</script>
```

could you help me please ?

Comment: I remenber having a similar issue at least a year before. Will check my code and docs cause I remember something that should be different than in docs...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

missing a comma before options:

```
}

options: {
```